# Performant way of displaying the number of unique column entries in a set of files?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, command-line

I'm attempting to pipe a large amount of files in to a sequence of commands which displays the number of unique entries in a given column of said files. I'm inexperienced with the shell, but after a short while I was able to come up with this:

```
awk '{print $5 }' | sort | uniq | wc - l
```

This sequence of commands works fine for a small amount of files, but takes an unacceptable amount of time to execute on my target set. Is there a set of commands that can accomplish this more efficiently?

Comment: You can use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`.

Comment: About how many lines of input are you actually trying to process? Can you please include a short bit of sample input data so we can see what you're really trying to do? Please also include your expected output with the sample input you provide. Are you looking for the unique items in column 5 in EACH file, or in ALL files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count unique occurrences of values in the fifth field in a single pass with awk:

```
awk '{if (!seen[$5]++) ++ctr} END {print ctr}'
```

This creates an array of the values in the fifth field and increments the `ctr` variable if the value has never seen before. The `END` rule prints the value of the counter.

With GNU awk, you can alternatively just check the length of the associative array in the end:

```
awk '{seen[$5]++} END {print length(seen)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin has supplied the good oil, but depending on just how much data is to be stored in the array, it may pay to pass the data to wc anyway:

```
awk '!_[$5]++' file | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

the sortest and fastest (i could) using awk but not far from previous version of @BenjaminW. I think a bit faster (difference could only be interesting on very huge file) because of test made earlier in the process

```
awk '!E[$5]++{c++}END{print c}' YourFile
```

works with all awk version

Answer (score 1):

*GNU* [`datamash`](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) has a *count* function for columns:

```
datamash -W count 5
```